# how to get first argument from url in javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I just wanted to find my first argument from my url.

like

```
http://www.google.co.in/webhp?ix=teb&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
```

I just wanted to string "ix=teb".

How to get that string only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
window.location.search.replace("?", "").split("&")[0];
```

update:

in case there's a variable holding url:

```
url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("?") + 1).split("&")[0];
```

Comment: Ugh, there's got to be a better way to do this. URL parsing aren't easy.

Comment: URL parsing yes, there are variety of Schemes, Ports, Hosts and IPs to accomplish this URL pattern, However Query String pattern in Http binding is fairly simple

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to read out parts of the URL:

```
window.location.search.match(/\?([^&$]+)/)[1] // == 'ix=teb'
```

In the event that there isn't anything in the query string of the URL, this would cause an error, so you should include some type checking like:

```
var queryStringMatch = window.location.search.match(/\?([^&$]+)/);
if(queryStringMatch) {
   // do something with queryStringMatch[1]
}
```